# Problem setting X axis values in MP Android Chart

Tags: java, android, graph, charts, linechart

I want to make a simple line chart, and im trying to define the X Axis values, but the output is not what i expected.

**Java Code**

```
 values.add(new Entry(1, 10));
        values.add(new Entry(2, 20));
        values.add(new Entry(3, 30));

        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Data");
        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Sample Data");


        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);


       final ArrayList<String> xLabels = new ArrayList<>();
        xLabels.add("1");
        xLabels.add("2");
        xLabels.add("3");


        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return xLabels.get((int) value);
            }

        });

        // create a data object with the data sets
        LineData data = new LineData(set1);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        data.setValueTextSize(9f);

        chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        chart.setData(data);
```

[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY7wY.png)

Why is it printing 6 values? Shouldnt be only 3 values (1,2,3) ?